# RTP $P(\bigcap A_i) >= 1 - \sum P(A^c_i)$

Tags: probability, boolean-algebra

I just got thru studying booles ineq and did some questions now i reached here and i am stuck. I tried implementing ^c to booled eq and i cant seem to get the missing line i need.

Comment: It's very unclear what you want. You need to provide some of the work you've done to get to where you're stuck, or really show us what you're stuck with at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(\cap A_i)=P((\cup A_i^c)^c)=1-P(\cup A_i^c)\geq 1-\sum P(A_i^c)$